# Node.js Readable file stream not getting data

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm attempting to create a Readable file stream that I can read individual bytes from.  I'm using the code below.

```js
var rs = fs.createReadStream(file).on('open', function() {
    var buff = rs.read(8); //Read first 8 bytes
    console.log(buff);
});
```

Given that file is an existing file of at least 8 bytes, why am I getting 'null' as the output for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Event `open` means that stream has been initialized, it does not mean you can read from the stream. You would have to listen for either `readable` or `data` events.

```
var rs = fs.createReadStream(file);

rs.once('readable', function() {
    var buff = rs.read(8); //Read first 8 bytes only once
    console.log(buff.toString());
});
```

Comment: I cannot use your second method, `rs.read(8)` always returns null. I can only read if I wait for the event `readable`.

Comment: @ffleandro I have removed that part. I guess it doesn't work anymore. This first method is the correct way to read.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're calling [this `rs.read()` method](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_read_size). However, that method is only available in the Streams interface. In the Streams interface, you're looking for the `'data'` event and not the `'open'` event.

That stated, the docs actually recommend against doing this. Instead you should probably be handling chunks at a time if you want to stream them:

```
var rs = fs.createReadStream('test.txt');

rs.on('data', function(chunk) {
    console.log(chunk);
});
```

If you want to read just a specific portion of a file, you may want to look at `fs.open()` and `fs.read()` which are lower level.

Comment: Won't attaching a data handler cause the stream to go into flowing mode?  I probably should have specified that I wanted to use non-flowing mode in the question.

Comment: Yeah, I had been working at the lower level, before attempting streams.  I liked the certainty of `rs.read` always returning the right number of bytes (or null, if there aren't that many), rather than fs.read, which may return fewer bytes than requested.