# How do you read a file or Stream synchronously in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Please, no lectures about how I should be doing everything asynchronously.  Sometimes I want to do things the easy obvious way, so I can move on to other work.

For some reason, the following code doesn't work.  It matches code I found on a [recent SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158806/node-js-readable-file-stream-not-getting-data).  Did node change or break something?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var rs = fs.createReadStream('myfilename');  // for example
                                             // but I might also want to read from
                                             // stdio, an HTTP request, etc...
var buffer = rs.read();     // simple for SCCCE example, normally you'd repeat in a loop...
console.log(buffer.toString());
```

After the read, the buffer is null.

Looking at rs in the debugger, I see

```
events  
   has end and open functions, nothing else
_readableState
  buffer = Array[0]
  emittedReadable = false
  flowing = false   <<< this appears to be correct
  lots of other false/nulls/undefined
fd = null   <<< suspicious???
readable = true
  lots of other false/nulls/undefined
```

Comment: use readFileSync http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options

Comment: Yes, but, I'd also like to be able to read from Streams, not just files. My bad, edited the question to clarify.

Comment: @user949300  `buffer` is `null` because there is no data available to read from the stream yet. You need to listen to the `readdable` event then call `rs.read()`

Comment: @Bulkan but calling `readableStream.on('readable', callback)` is asynchronous.  I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: @user949300 streams are inherently asynchronous. There is no way to use them in a synchronous manner.

Comment: It is possible Bulkan, see my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010915/parsing-huge-logfiles-in-node-js-read-in-line-by-line/23695940#23695940

Answer (score 10):

To read the contents of a file synchronously use [fs.readFileSync](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options)

```
var fs = require('fs');
var content = fs.readFileSync('myfilename');
console.log(content);
```

[fs.createReadStream](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) creates a [ReadStream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable).

Comment: Yes, but, I'd also like to be able to read from Streams, not just files.  My bad, edited the question to clarify.

Comment: @user949300 [fs.readSync](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readsync_fd_buffer_offset_length_position) might help in that case.

Comment: I think that would work with stdin, via process.stdin.fd, but not sure how that helps wit a stream, say, from an HTTP file upload.

Comment: @user949300 did you get an answer for reading a stream into a string synchronously?

Comment: @Shubham.   No.  I reworked the code for asynch, but still seems like reading a stream sync (e.g. at startup) would be useful