# How do I read a file in Node.js without using callback?

Tags: node.js, file, synchronization

I am trying to read a file in node.js but I am getting tired of writing so many callbacks. Is there a way I can just read a file in one line?

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: `filedata = require('fs').readFileSync(filename);` will do.

Comment: See answer in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918326/how-do-you-read-a-file-or-stream-synchronously-in-node-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just loading a config or a template you can use the sync read method

`var my fileData = fs.readFileSync('myFileName');`

If you need you do it as a reply to an http request you can use the streaming API

```
function (req, res) {
  fs.createReadStream('myFileName').pipe(res);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks are king, but you can use anonymous callbacks...

```
fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
});
```

http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback